# Return a multidimensional array of bools from color values of sections inside a canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, multidimensional-array

### **Question:**

How can I loop over a 100px by 100px canvas in increments of 10px by 10px squares and return multidimensional array of booleans.  Booleans being truthy when a red pixel is present **anywhere** inside of that 10px by 10px square.

**In the end the output will look like this:**

```
var theMatrix =[[true, false, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true],
 [false, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, true, true]
 [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false]
 ...
]
```

**app.js:**

```
    var source = new Image();
        source.src = 'path/alaska.svg';

    source.onload = function() {
        var svgDimensions  = {
            w: this.width,
            h: this.height
        };
        setCanvasSize(svgDimensions);
    };

    var el = element[0],
        ctx = el.getContext('2d');

    function setCanvasSize(svg) {
        el.width = svg.w;
        el.height = svg.h;
        ctx.drawImage(source,0,0);
        readImage();
    }

    function readImage() {
        var theMatrix = [];
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,el.width,el.height),
            data = imgData.data;    
        //this i+=4 is not correct way to loop through 10x10 squares of the canvas
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i+=4) {
            var red = data[i];
            if(red > 0){
                theMatrix.push(true); //this push isn't proper to create the multidimensional array that I'm looking to output
            }
        }
        printOutput(theMatrix);
    }
    function printOutput(trix) {
       console.log(trix) this will be output described above.
    }
```

**this code will draw out a red alaska like so**

[image]
(not to scale) Figure is just to describe the process:
[image]
And output of `theMatrix` array could be visualized like this:
[image]

Comment: Drawing SVG on canvas in some browsers will "taint" the canvas and cause `.getImageData` to be disallowed. Maybe use a .jpg or .png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getImagData` lets you read a rectangle from a specified position in the canvas which I used in the code below.

```
function readImage()
{   var theMatrix = [];
    var row, col, rowMatrix, imgData, data, red, i;

    for(row = 0; row < 10; ++row)
    {   rowMatrix = [];
        for(col = 0; col < 10; ++col)
        {   imgData = ctx.getImageData( 10*col, 10*row, 10, 10)
            data = imgData.data;
            // start from i = 0 for red channel
            // start from i = 3 for alpha channel
            for( i = 0, red=false; i < data.length; i+=4)
            {   if( data[i])
                {   red=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            rowMatrix.push( red);
        }
        theMatrix.push( rowMatrix);
     }
     printOutput(theMatrix);
}
```

Hope it helps with the general principle and is only written for a 100px x 100px image.

---

Note the test for redness relies on the image having a transparent background with background pixel values of zero. When tested with a .png file with transparent background this was the case.

I would still recommend changing the test from the red channel to the alpha channel to make this reliance more obvious in code.

Comment: Doing `.getImageData` on each 10x10 area is a good plan. You might take the time to improve your *isRed* test as noted in your update.

Comment: Since the image seems mono-colored, testing the alpha value is also a good plan. Upvote.

Comment: @markE thanks and good catch. I've changed the update entirely based on results found in testing with a .png file. If the image has a transparent background all works well!